# Замена слов в исходной строке при помощи регулярных выражений

Tags: php

```
$string = 'Машинист Машиниста Машинисту Машиниста Машинистом Машинисте Машинисты Машинистам Машинистов Машинистам Машинистах';
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0]= '/машинист/';
$patterns[1]= '/Машиниста/';
$patterns[2]= '/Машинисту/';
$patterns[3]= '/Машиниста/';
$patterns[4]= '/Машинистом/';
$patterns[5]= '/Машинисте/';
$patterns[6]= '/Машинисты/';
$patterns[7]= '/Машинистов/';
$patterns[8]= '/Машинистам/';
$patterns[9]= '/Машинистов/';
$patterns[10]= '/Машинистами/';
$patterns[11]= '/Машинистах/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = 'турист';
$replacements[1] = 'туриста';
$replacements[2] = 'туристу';
$replacements[3] = 'туриста';
$replacements[4] = 'туристом';
$replacements[5] = 'туристе';
$replacements[6] = 'туристы';
$replacements[7] = 'туристов';
$replacements[8] = 'туристами';
$replacements[9] = 'туристов';
$replacements[10] = 'туристами';
$replacements[11] = 'туристах';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string );
```

Как можно упростить регулярное выражение по замене слов с падежами?

Comment: Если слова именно эти то str_replace('машинист','турист') даст требуемый эффетк. можно конечно регуляркой еще проверить на допустимость окончаний. Но далеко не все слова так можно будет заменить потому как всякие беглые гласные и т.п. в некоторых словах не позволят это сделать

Comment: в данном случае только эти пару слов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оставить как есть будет оптимальным вариантом. С точки зрения читабельности)

Кстати под ключом '8' разве равнозначная замена?

```
$patterns[8]= '/Машинистам/';
$replacements[8] = 'туристами';
```

Если у вас опечатка и окончания одинаковые и слова только эти, можно даже без регулярных:

```
$string = str_replace('Машинист', 'турист', $string);
```

**UPD:**

Еще можно так заменить, имхо более читабельно:

```
$replacements = array(
    'машинист' => 'турист',
    'Машиниста' => 'туриста',
    'Машинисту' => 'туристу',
    'Машинистом' => 'туристом',
);

$string = str_replace(array_keys($replacements), array_values($replacements), $string);
```

Comment: да это опечатка

Answer (score 2):

Если окончания надо проверять, что бы, например случайно не поменять слово 'Машинистка' то:

```
preg_replace('/Машинист(?=(а(ми?|х|)|[уеы]|о[мв]|)\b)/ui','турист',$str);
```

А если не надо, то простой `str_replace('Машинист', 'турист', $str);` правда он, в отличие от preg_replace не может работать с разными регистрами символов.